# Custom UIView does not fit in bounds of screen , Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, xib

I have a custom UIView that I am loading from an xib file, when running in the simulator the view seems to be clipped on the right side. Iv'e attempted to change the properties in "view.autoresizingmask" however playing with the different options available does not help , also Working with different constraint options also does not solve the problem,

the code I used in the swift file for my custom view class are as followed :

```
  var view : UIView!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    loadViewFromNib ()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    loadViewFromNib ()
}
func loadViewFromNib() {
    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "LeaderBoardView", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleHeight, .FlexibleWidth]
    self.addSubview(view);

}
```

[This is an image of the xib file ( Keep in mind the view that this xib is loaded into are the same dimensions as the file )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iXUZ.png)

[This image comes from the simulator and here you see how the view will not fit in the bounds of the screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99nXS.png)

SB : there is also a slight rendering issue that occurs , Perhaps there's code that may help resolve this issue. Error message is as follows
"Failed to render instance of LeaderBoardView: Rendering the view took longer than 200 ms. Your drawing code may suffer from slow performance."

Answer (score 0):

Don't create view in`loadViewFromNib` again, you've already added on top, just:

```
view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
```

and `bundle` can be `nil`